# Presheaf kernel is a presheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I'm reading Vakil's the The Rising Sea note, and I'm stuck on a quite trivial question.

> Let $\mathscr{F},\mathscr{G}$ be presheaves of abelian groups on a topological space $X$. Let $f:\mathscr{F}\rightarrow \mathscr{G}$ be a morphism between presheaves. The presheaf kernel $\ker_{\text{pre}}f$ is defined by $\ker_{\text{pre}}f(U)=\ker f(U)$ for each open subset $U\subseteq X$. Show that $\ker_{\text{pre}}f$ is a presheaf.

[image]

I'm guessing that the function in the hint is the induced map $\text{res}_{V, U}: \mathscr{G}(V)/f(V)(\mathscr{F}(V)) \rightarrow \mathscr{G}(U)/f(U)(\mathscr{F}(U))$ from the diagram chasing, but I'm not exactly sure what I should do with it. Should I try to compute $\ker_{\text{pre}}f(V) \rightarrow\ker_{\text{pre}}f(U)$ by writing down a composition through $\text{res}_{V, U}:\mathscr{G}(V)/f(V)(\mathscr{F}(V)) \rightarrow \mathscr{G}(U)/f(U)(\mathscr{F}(U))$?

Comment: The unique map of the hint gives you your restriction maps. To show they compose as desired, just append the same diagram along the bottom line, and apply uniqueness of maps.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I understand. The issue is I think that the restriction map given in the hint is not $\ker_{pre}f(V) \rightarrow \ker_{pre} f(U)$ because $\mathscr{G}(V)/f(V)(\mathscr{F}(V))$ is not included in $\ker_{pre} f(V) = \ker f(V) \subset \mathscr{F}(U)$. So I'm not exactly sure how is the map from the hint is going to help me come up a restriction for the kernel presheaf.

Comment: Don't think of these objects as sets with a notion of inclusion. We are constructing these maps by the universal property of the kernel in an abelian category. F and G could be sheaves on any abelian category. I can write a more detailed answer if this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Because restriction maps commute with our morphism arrows on sections, we have that if
$$0\longrightarrow \ker_{\text{pre}} f(V) \xrightarrow{\phi}\mathscr{F}(V)\xrightarrow{f(V)}\mathscr{G}(V)$$
is the kernel of $f(V)$ (in the category theoretic sense, i.e. in whatever abelian category $\mathscr{F}(\cdot)$ belongs to), then
$$f(U)\circ \text{res}_{V,U}\circ \phi = \text{res}_{V,U}\circ \underbrace{f(V)\circ \phi}_{0} = 0.$$
Thus by the universal property of $\ker_{\text{pre}} f(U)$, we get a unique arrow $\mu$ (up to unique isomorphism)
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> \ker_{\text{pre}}f(V) @>\phi>> \mathscr{F}(V) @>f(V)>> \mathscr{G}(V) \\
\ @V\mu VV @V{\text{res}_{V,U}}VV @V{\text{res}_{V,U}}VV \\
0 @>>> \ker_{\text{pre}}f(U) @>>> \mathscr{F}(U) @>f(U)>> \mathscr{G}(U)
\end{CD}$$
We make this map $\mu$ our restriction map $\text{res}_{V,U} : \ker_{\text{pre}} f(V) \to \ker_{\text{pre}} f(U)$.
For proper composition, just chain the diagrams:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> \ker_{\text{pre}}f(V) @>>> \mathscr{F}(V) @>f(V)>> \mathscr{G}(V) \\
\ @VVV @V{\text{res}_{V,U}}VV @V{\text{res}_{V,U}}VV \\
0 @>>> \ker_{\text{pre}}f(U) @>>> \mathscr{F}(U) @>f(U)>> \mathscr{G}(U) \\
\ @VVV @V{\text{res}_{U,W}}VV @V{\text{res}_{U,W}}VV \\
0 @>>> \ker_{\text{pre}}f(W) @>>> \mathscr{F}(W) @>f(W)>> \mathscr{G}(W)
\end{CD}$$
By uniqueness of the map induced by the universal property, we must have that $\text{res}_{U, W}\circ \text{res}_{V,U} = \text{res}_{V,W}$ since this diagram commutes.